# Change Python code to Node.js code (base64 / hmac256 Encoding)

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, base64, hmac

First of All, Sorry for my poor English and Thanks for clicking this Question.

I am trying to change my python codes to Node.js Code. (about base64 / HMAC encoding)

The problem is I can't find adequate way of changing below python codes to Node.js Codes

```py
    passphrase = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

I just want to use node's *crypto* module, but There is only one argument option after first 'sha256' argument like below.

```js
crypto.createHmac('sha256', api_secret);
// There is no argument position of 'api_passphrase'
```

How can I create hmac with ***two*** arguments like python codes on node.js?

Comment: You must use the `update()` method in the NodeJS code to pass the message and the `digest()` method for finalization. See the [examples](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hmac) in the documentation.

Comment: @Topaco thx, digesting as 'binary' seems right, like `.digest('binary')` right?

Comment: In the Python code you use a base64 encoding (`base64.b64encode()`), so it should be `.digest('base64')`. Just compare the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On python,

```py
signature = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

On Node.js

```js
signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', api_secret).update(str_to_sign).digest('base64');
```